# Meteor: redirect a collection update to a service call

Tags: meteor

Following the example [here](http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-data-from-an-external-api/) I am able to use Meteor's subscribe system to call an external service and have the results published through a subscription to the client. While I'm not sure this is really a better way to go then just using a meteor method or calling the service form the client, it does have interesting possibilities.

What I am curious about now is can I do this the other way around too, have client issue an insert or update to the collection on the client side, and have the server side catch it, redirect it to a service instead and then return the result? This would allow for some of the built in optimistic UI stuff to still work on the client, and the client to get notified if the update service call failed. Any ideas how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Use collection hooks, update the collection on the server side in the callback from the remote service?

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd, I think for collection hooks I need an actual collection to update, as the collection update will run anyway. I have no real mongo collections, just external API services.

Comment: Use collections as cache. You deal with getting data to/from your API services into the server side collection, let Meteor DDP get that to/from the client.